# A question about convergence in $L^p$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

Let $E$ be measurable and $1 \le p \le \infty$. Suppose $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ all measurable and $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \to f$ pointwise a.e. $E$. For $p$ as above, I want to show that:

$$\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \to f \in L^p(E)$$ 
if there is $\theta >0$ such that $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ belongs to and is bounded as a subset of $L^{p + \theta}(E)$.

One of the things that give me trouble is that I cannot understand the mathematical meaning of "belongs to and is bounded as a subset of" in this context.

Comment: They mean that, for each $n$, $f_n \in L^{p + \theta}(E)$. This is the "belongs to" portion. Furthermore, they want that there exists an $M > 0$ such that $\|f_n\|_{L^{p + \theta}} \le M$  for every $n$. This is the "bounded as a subset of" portion.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283920/pointwise-a-e-convergence-implies-strong-convergence/283940). I think you want $E$ to have finite measure.